# Get Pixel color of UIImage

Tags: iphone, uiimage, rgb, pixel

How can I get the RGB value of a particular pixel in a UIImage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't access the raw data directly, but by getting the CGImage of this image you can access it. here is a link to another question that answers your question and others you might have regarding detailed image manipulation : [CGImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

Answer (score 92):

Try this very simple code:

I used to detect a wall in my maze game (the only info that I need is the alpha channel, but I included the code to get the other colors for you):

```
- (BOOL)isWallPixel:(UIImage *)image xCoordinate:(int)x yCoordinate:(int)y {

    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
    const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

    int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width  * y) + x ) * 4; // The image is png

    //UInt8 red = data[pixelInfo];         // If you need this info, enable it
    //UInt8 green = data[(pixelInfo + 1)]; // If you need this info, enable it
    //UInt8 blue = data[pixelInfo + 2];    // If you need this info, enable it
    UInt8 alpha = data[pixelInfo + 3];     // I need only this info for my maze game
    CFRelease(pixelData);

    //UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha/255.0f]; // The pixel color info

    if (alpha) return YES;
    else return NO;

}
```

Comment: could you help me in getting the position of the pixel relative to the image size.  I'm using this for the positioning of objects in my game. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but did not understand your question. Can you be more specific?
Post some example code? Do you want to find a pixel in an image?

Comment: x and y are the coordinates of image you want to get info.

Comment: @MinasPetterson Would this work for any UIImage of only for the ones initiated with PNGs?

Comment: Note this will crash horribly on a greyscale image. The first "*4" needs to be "*(number of color components)" i.e. 1 for greyscale PNG

Comment: This works fine on an RGBA image. What if the image is ARGB? And more importantly, how do you detect if the image is ARGB? (because the rest is easy, you just switch the order of the red, green, blue and alpha vars)

Comment: I found (a part of) the answer: CGImageGetAlphaInfo(image.CGImage). But the thing is that if the answer is kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst the values are weird. For example a red pixel with 255 alpha is [0 0 255 255] instead of (what I hould guess as) [255 255 0 0] any ideas?

Comment: @MinasPetterson, this worked perfectly for me until now, but in the iPhone6plus simulator the values are very weird. Any idea why?

Comment: @TiagoLira I think it's because of scale factor (iPhone 6 plus has 3x scale factor), so when calculating x and y values you must add scale factor to account.

Comment: Getting the pixel info line should have been as follows:
     int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width  * y) * 4 ) + x;
Because the pixel offset can be found by using (width * y * 4) + x;
and getting the RGB values as follows:
     UInt8 alpha = data[pixelInfo];
     UInt8 red = data[pixelInfo+1];
     UInt8 green = data[pixelInfo+2];
     UInt8 blue = data[pixelInfo+3];

Comment: Shanmugaraja, 4 * (w * y + x) is correct. Think of it as a matrix of 32bit numbers: the location is (w*y + x) to find the 32bit pixel. Now, convert 32bit colors to bytes by multiplying by 4.

Comment: @minas this method was working fine till now. .i was using this since 2 yr. . But suddenly i got the issue. My image have white background image rather alpha giving 0 value. .  what should be the issue ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999305/issue-in-checking-uiimag-have-alpha-transparant-color-or-not see this is my question for better understanding.

Comment: I think I'm having similar issue as @Gik. I have a .png with only the color red in it and end up with yellow? Image is here: https://s29.postimg.org/5mv445347/red.png

Answer (score 19):

**OnTouch**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint point1 = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; 
    if ([touch view] == imgZoneWheel)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:imgZoneWheel];
        [self getPixelColorAtLocation:location];
        if(alpha==255)
        {
            NSLog(@"In Image Touch view alpha %d",alpha);
            [self translateCurrentTouchPoint:point1.x :point1.y];
            [imgZoneWheel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"blue%d.png",GrndFild]]];
        }
    }
}



- (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point 
{

    UIColor* color = nil;

    CGImageRef inImage;

    inImage = imgZoneWheel.image.CGImage;


    // Create off screen bitmap context to draw the image into. Format ARGB is 4 bytes for each pixel: Alpa, Red, Green, Blue
    CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
    if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; /* error */ }

    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}};


    // Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory 
    // allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the 
    // raw image data in the specified color space.
    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, inImage); 

    // Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
    // context.
    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
    if (data != NULL) {
        //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y. 
        //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
        int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
        alpha =  data[offset]; 
        int red = data[offset+1]; 
        int green = data[offset+2]; 
        int blue = data[offset+3]; 
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];
    }

    // When finished, release the context
    //CGContextRelease(cgctx); 
    // Free image data memory for the context
    if (data) { free(data); }

    return color;
}

- (CGContextRef) createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:(CGImageRef)inImage 
{
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
    size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    // Use the generic RGB color space.
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (bitmapData == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits 
    // per component. Regardless of what the source image format is 
    // (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
    // specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    if (context == NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    }

    // Make sure and release colorspace before returning
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
}
```

Comment: `point = CGPointMake(point.x * image.scale, point.y * image.scale);`

Comment: This is the best answer since it accounts for pixel format. It can be any format and it will be transformed to ARGB. Thank you

Comment: A work method that are valid for Display P3!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 17):

Some Swift code based on Minas' answer. Originally I had some code to figure out the pixel stride, but I've updated the answer to use the ComponentLayout from [Desmond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60247648/1765629). I've also moved the extension to CGImage.

**Swift 5:**

```swift
public extension UIImage {
    func getPixelColor(_ point: CGPoint) -> UIColor {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else {
            return UIColor.clear
        }
        return cgImage.getPixelColor(point)
    }
}
public extension CGBitmapInfo {
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60247648/1765629
    // I've extended it to include .a
    enum ComponentLayout {

        case a
        case bgra
        case abgr
        case argb
        case rgba
        case bgr
        case rgb

        var count: Int {
            switch self {
            case .a: return 1
            case .bgr, .rgb: return 3
            default: return 4
            }
        }
    }

    var isAlphaPremultiplied: Bool {
        let alphaInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo(rawValue: rawValue & Self.alphaInfoMask.rawValue)
        return alphaInfo == .premultipliedFirst || alphaInfo == .premultipliedLast
    }

    // [...] skipping the rest
}

public extension CGImage {

    func getPixelColor(_ point: CGPoint) -> UIColor {
        guard let pixelData = self.dataProvider?.data, let layout = bitmapInfo.componentLayout, let data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData) else {
            return .clear
        }
        let x = Int(point.x)
        let y = Int(point.y)
        let w = self.width
        let h = self.height
        let index = w * y + x
        let numBytes = CFDataGetLength(pixelData)
        let numComponents = layout.count
        if numBytes != w * h * numComponents {
            NSLog("Unexpected size: \(numBytes) != \(w)x\(h)x\(numComponents)")
            return .clear
        }
        let isAlphaPremultiplied = bitmapInfo.isAlphaPremultiplied
        switch numComponents {
        case 1:
            return UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: CGFloat(data[index])/255.0)
        case 3:
            let c0 = CGFloat((data[3*index])) / 255
            let c1 = CGFloat((data[3*index+1])) / 255
            let c2 = CGFloat((data[3*index+2])) / 255
            if layout == .bgr {
                return UIColor(red: c2, green: c1, blue: c0, alpha: 1.0)
            }
            return UIColor(red: c0, green: c1, blue: c2, alpha: 1.0)
        case 4:
            let c0 = CGFloat((data[4*index])) / 255
            let c1 = CGFloat((data[4*index+1])) / 255
            let c2 = CGFloat((data[4*index+2])) / 255
            let c3 = CGFloat((data[4*index+3])) / 255
            var r: CGFloat = 0
            var g: CGFloat = 0
            var b: CGFloat = 0
            var a: CGFloat = 0
            switch layout {
            case .abgr:
                a = c0; b = c1; g = c2; r = c3
            case .argb:
                a = c0; r = c1; g = c2; b = c3
            case .bgra:
                b = c0; g = c1; r = c2; a = c3
            case .rgba:
                r = c0; g = c1; b = c2; a = c3
            default:
                break
            }
            if isAlphaPremultiplied && a > 0 {
                r = r / a
                g = g / a
                b = b / a
            }
            return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
        default:
            return .clear
        }
    }
```

I was trying to refactor it to use ranges, but this doesn't seem to work,

```swift
    let start = numComponents * index
    let end = numComponents * (index + 1)
    let c = data[start ..< end] // expects Int, not a Range...
```

Comment: Question to others since I'm not so sure. I'd think if there is only 1 byte per pixel, it would be the white value, not the alpha value. Can others confirm?

Comment: It can be either; you have to make that judgement call. The image could be a greyscale image, in which case the value would be white, but it could also be a transparency mask, in which case it would be alpha. I'd say that transparency masks are probably more common these days than greyscale images so the decision to use alpha is justified. Personally though, I think this could be improved upon in the specific instance since it is not efficient to do all this code every time a pixel is tested when iterating a large number of pixels.

Comment: n.b. you can find out if an image is a mask using the `isMask` property of `CGImage`.

Comment: Don't use `image.size`, use `cgImage.width` and `cgImage.height` instead. Also, adjust the given point using `image.scale`. Otherwise this code won't work with Retina images (@2x and @3x)

Comment: Improved answer to add support for grayscale images

Comment: I'm getting a compile error with this: `Value of type 'CGBitmapInfo' has no member 'isAlphaPremultiplied'`

Comment: Darren, I've added the definition of `isAlphaPremultiplied` for clarity. I had omitted originally because it comes from Desmond's answer. Please follow the link and check the extended definitions of `CGBitmapInfo` that he proposes.

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 5 version**

The answers given here are either outdated or incorrect because they don't take into account the following:

1. The pixel size of the image can differ from its point size that is returned by `image.size.width`/`image.size.height`.
2. There can be various layouts used by pixel components in the image, such as BGRA, ABGR, ARGB etc. or may not have an alpha component at all, such as BGR and RGB. For example, `UIView.drawHierarchy(in:afterScreenUpdates:)` method can produce BGRA images.
3. Color components can be premultiplied by the alpha for all pixels in the image and need to be divided by alpha in order to restore the original color.
4. For memory optimization used by `CGImage`, the size of a pixel row in bytes can be greater than the mere multiplication of the pixel width by 4.

The code below is to provide a universal Swift 5 solution to get the `UIColor` of a pixel for all such special cases. The code is optimized for usability and clarity, *not* for performance.

```swift
public extension UIImage {
    var pixelWidth: Int {
        return cgImage?.width ?? 0
    }

    var pixelHeight: Int {
        return cgImage?.height ?? 0
    }

    func pixelColor(x: Int, y: Int) -> UIColor {
        assert(
            0 ..< pixelWidth ~= x && 0 ..< pixelHeight ~= y,
            "Pixel coordinates are out of bounds"
        )

        guard
            let cgImage = cgImage,
            let data = cgImage.dataProvider?.data,
            let dataPtr = CFDataGetBytePtr(data),
            let colorSpaceModel = cgImage.colorSpace?.model,
            let componentLayout = cgImage.bitmapInfo.componentLayout
        else {
            assertionFailure("Could not get a pixel of an image")
            return .clear
        }

        assert(
            colorSpaceModel == .rgb,
            "The only supported color space model is RGB"
        )
        assert(
            cgImage.bitsPerPixel == 32 || cgImage.bitsPerPixel == 24,
            "A pixel is expected to be either 4 or 3 bytes in size"
        )

        let bytesPerRow = cgImage.bytesPerRow
        let bytesPerPixel = cgImage.bitsPerPixel / 8
        let pixelOffset = y * bytesPerRow + x * bytesPerPixel

        if componentLayout.count == 4 {
            let components = (
                dataPtr[pixelOffset + 0],
                dataPtr[pixelOffset + 1],
                dataPtr[pixelOffset + 2],
                dataPtr[pixelOffset + 3]
            )

            var alpha: UInt8 = 0
            var red: UInt8 = 0
            var green: UInt8 = 0
            var blue: UInt8 = 0

            switch componentLayout {
            case .bgra:
                alpha = components.3
                red = components.2
                green = components.1
                blue = components.0
            case .abgr:
                alpha = components.0
                red = components.3
                green = components.2
                blue = components.1
            case .argb:
                alpha = components.0
                red = components.1
                green = components.2
                blue = components.3
            case .rgba:
                alpha = components.3
                red = components.0
                green = components.1
                blue = components.2
            default:
                return .clear
            }

            /// If chroma components are premultiplied by alpha and the alpha is `0`,
            /// keep the chroma components to their current values.
            if cgImage.bitmapInfo.chromaIsPremultipliedByAlpha, alpha != 0 {
                let invisibleUnitAlpha = 255 / CGFloat(alpha)
                red = UInt8((CGFloat(red) * invisibleUnitAlpha).rounded())
                green = UInt8((CGFloat(green) * invisibleUnitAlpha).rounded())
                blue = UInt8((CGFloat(blue) * invisibleUnitAlpha).rounded())
            }

            return .init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)

        } else if componentLayout.count == 3 {
            let components = (
                dataPtr[pixelOffset + 0],
                dataPtr[pixelOffset + 1],
                dataPtr[pixelOffset + 2]
            )

            var red: UInt8 = 0
            var green: UInt8 = 0
            var blue: UInt8 = 0

            switch componentLayout {
            case .bgr:
                red = components.2
                green = components.1
                blue = components.0
            case .rgb:
                red = components.0
                green = components.1
                blue = components.2
            default:
                return .clear
            }

            return .init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: UInt8(255))

        } else {
            assertionFailure("Unsupported number of pixel components")
            return .clear
        }
    }
}

public extension UIColor {
    convenience init(red: UInt8, green: UInt8, blue: UInt8, alpha: UInt8) {
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat(red) / 255,
            green: CGFloat(green) / 255,
            blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255,
            alpha: CGFloat(alpha) / 255
        )
    }
}

public extension CGBitmapInfo {
    enum ComponentLayout {
        case bgra
        case abgr
        case argb
        case rgba
        case bgr
        case rgb

        var count: Int {
            switch self {
            case .bgr, .rgb: return 3
            default: return 4
            }
        }
    }

    var componentLayout: ComponentLayout? {
        guard let alphaInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo(rawValue: rawValue & Self.alphaInfoMask.rawValue) else { return nil }
        let isLittleEndian = contains(.byteOrder32Little)

        if alphaInfo == .none {
            return isLittleEndian ? .bgr : .rgb
        }
        let alphaIsFirst = alphaInfo == .premultipliedFirst || alphaInfo == .first || alphaInfo == .noneSkipFirst

        if isLittleEndian {
            return alphaIsFirst ? .bgra : .abgr
        } else {
            return alphaIsFirst ? .argb : .rgba
        }
    }

    var chromaIsPremultipliedByAlpha: Bool {
        let alphaInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo(rawValue: rawValue & Self.alphaInfoMask.rawValue)
        return alphaInfo == .premultipliedFirst || alphaInfo == .premultipliedLast
    }
}
```

Comment: I did some more reading and see that in little endian the components are swapped, so your code is correct. Thanks for your comments. Great and robust answer.

Comment: Ngl I picked up a few new things from this answer. Code it very elaborate. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a generic method for getting pixel color in a UI image, building on Minas Petterson's answer:

```
- (UIColor*)pixelColorInImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)x atY:(int)y {

    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
    const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

    int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width * y) + x ) * 4; // 4 bytes per pixel

    UInt8 red   = data[pixelInfo + 0];
    UInt8 green = data[pixelInfo + 1];
    UInt8 blue  = data[pixelInfo + 2];
    UInt8 alpha = data[pixelInfo + 3];
    CFRelease(pixelData);

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red  /255.0f
                           green:green/255.0f
                            blue:blue /255.0f
                           alpha:alpha/255.0f];
}
```

Note that X and Y may be swapped; this function accesses the underlying bitmap directly and doesn't consider rotations that may be part of the UIImage.

Comment: Is there a way to put the image back together with these color numbers?

Comment: this function does not consider format either, which is BGR for me.

Answer (score 7):

```
- (UIColor *)colorAtPixel:(CGPoint)point inImage:(UIImage *)image {

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height), point)) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a 1x1 pixel byte array and bitmap context to draw the pixel into.
    NSInteger pointX = trunc(point.x);
    NSInteger pointY = trunc(point.y);
    CGImageRef cgImage = image.CGImage;
    NSUInteger width = image.size.width;
    NSUInteger height = image.size.height;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    int bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * 1;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    unsigned char pixelData[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData, 1, 1, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);

    // Draw the pixel we are interested in onto the bitmap context
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -pointX, pointY-(CGFloat)height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), cgImage);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    // Convert color values [0..255] to floats [0.0..1.0]
    CGFloat red   = (CGFloat)pixelData[0] / 255.0f;
    CGFloat green = (CGFloat)pixelData[1] / 255.0f;
    CGFloat blue  = (CGFloat)pixelData[2] / 255.0f;
    CGFloat alpha = (CGFloat)pixelData[3] / 255.0f;
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
}
```

Comment: I think the result is wrong because the bitmap context's alpha info is *kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast*. However, when you retrieve the pixel colour, you treat it as the non-premultiplied value.

Answer (score 5):

Swift version of Minas answer

```
extension CGImage {
    func pixel(x: Int, y: Int) -> (r: Int, g: Int, b: Int, a: Int)? { // swiftlint:disable:this large_tuple
        guard let pixelData = dataProvider?.data,
            let data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData) else { return nil }

        let pixelInfo = ((width  * y) + x ) * 4

        let red = Int(data[pixelInfo])         // If you need this info, enable it
        let green = Int(data[(pixelInfo + 1)]) // If you need this info, enable it
        let blue = Int(data[pixelInfo + 2])    // If you need this info, enable it
        let alpha = Int(data[pixelInfo + 3])   // I need only this info for my maze game

        return (red, green, blue, alpha)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all create and attach tap gesture recognizer allow allow user interactions:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
[self.label addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
self.label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Now implement `-tapGesture:`

```
- (void)tapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.label];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.label.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.label.layer renderInContext:context];

    int bpr = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context);
    unsigned char * data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
    if (data != NULL)
    {
        int offset = bpr*round(point.y) + 4*round(point.x);
        int blue = data[offset+0];
        int green = data[offset+1];
        int red = data[offset+2];
        int alpha =  data[offset+3];

        NSLog(@"%d %d %d %d", alpha, red, green, blue);

        if (alpha == 0)
        {
            // Here is tap out of text
        }
        else
        {
            // Here is tap right into text
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

This will works on UILabel with transparent background, if this is not what you want you can compare alpha, red, green, blue with `self.label.backgroundColor`...

Comment: What does this have to do with a tap gesture?