# Extracting RGB & alpha value of an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, colors, color-picker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)
>   [Get Pixel color of UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284185/get-pixel-color-of-uiimage)

I have a scenario in which the user can select a color from an image, for example the one below:[image]

Depending on the tap location of the user on the image I need to extract the RGB and alpha value at that very point—or say, pixel.
How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a bitmap context (`CGContextRef`) from the image and convert the `CGPoint` that was tapped to an array offset location to retrieve the color information from the pixel data.

See [What Color is My Pixel?](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/) for a tutorial and this [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics).

Methods:

```
- (CGContextRef) createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:(CGImageRef) inImage
```

> Returns a `CGContextRef` representing the image passed as an argument
>   using the correct color space. This method is called by:

```
- (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint) point
```

> This is the function you would call to get the `UIColor` at the passed
>   `CGPoint`.

Note that these methods are in a subclass of a `UIImageView` to make the process more straightforward.