# Get Pixel color of Camera in Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I´m trying to develop an app to help people with vision diseases and one of the function is to recognize the color of the object that user is pointing.

I´ve read this article about how to get the pixel color from an UIImage

[Get Pixel color of UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284185/get-pixel-color-of-uiimage)

Anyone have a idea how i can get this pixel color from camera?

Answer (score 0):

Marcelo, there is quite a bit of setup to get the pixel color from camera. You will need to get up to speed with AVFoundation at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html

After you have done that, you should pull the sample code Rosy Writer:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html

This code is meant to take a live camera image and change one of the pixel colors.

I recommend you spend time on those 2 and then come back with more specific questions as you start build the app.

Hope this helps.