# Convert an image to CGBitmapContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I am relatively new in objective C, it is possible to convert a png image into a CGBitmapContext. If it is, How I can implement it.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Why do you think you need a CGBitmapContext? If you just want to draw, why not simply draw the image into a graphics context?

Comment: Yes, are you certain you need to use a `CGBitmapContext`? It's a low-level API; very powerful, but complex. Consider starting with `UIImage` and see if that does what you need. It can decode PNG files for you, and much more.

Comment: Hi Matt, My intention it is to obtain the pixel data RGB value from it  through a touch or a pan.

Comment: Any other simpler way to go?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

Comment: I don't mean to criticise (okay, yes I do, actually), but if that's what you want to know then that's what you should ask. You still really aren't stating clearly what question you want the answer to. Perhaps what you want to know is whether the pixel the user has tapped on is transparent; in that case, [see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042830/retrieving-a-pixel-alpha-value-for-a-uiimage/3763313#3763313). (And if you need fuller RGB info on a pixel, it's easy to see how to adapt that code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While pixel values are not possible to obtain from a UIImage, it can be accessed through  CGImage of the UIImage. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12579413/445312) provided in the post.
It uses the `onTouch` method to grab the RGB value at a particular x and y coordinate that the user's finger is on.

Answer (score 1):

That is the solution I found

```
- (IBAction)handlePans:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)event{
if (event.numberOfTouches==1){

tranx = [event locationInView:self].x;
trany = [event locationInView:self].y;

CGPoint vel = [event velocityInView:self];
    velocityx = vel.x;
    velocityy = vel.y;

// NSLog(@"x: %d y:%d", tranx,trany);
//NSLog(@"velocity x - %f", vel.x);
//NSLog(@"velocity y - %f", vel.y);

_imageselct = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GASOLINE.png"];
CFDataRef pixelData =  CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(_imageselct.CGImage));
const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
int pixelInfo = ((workingImage.size.width  * trany) + tranx ) * 4;
float red = data[pixelInfo];
float green = data[(pixelInfo+1)];
float blue = data[pixelInfo + 2];
float alpha = data[pixelInfo + 3];
CFRelease(pixelData);
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha/255.0f];

if ([color getRed:&red green: &green blue: &blue alpha: &alpha]){

    NSLog(@"r: %f g: %f b: %f a: %f", red, green, blue, alpha);



}

}
}
```

Comment: Performance note: CGDataProviderCopyData copies the entire image. I'm not an expert, but your original instinct to use CGBitmapContext might have been more efficient. Specifically, use CGBitmapContextGetData to get a *pointer* (rather than a copy). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12579413/199364