# How to Position a UIView on top of an UIImage across all iPhone devices and the simulators

Tags: swift, xcode, view, uiimageview, pixel

I am trying to get a view to position on top of an image.
I have an xCode App with an iPhone image in an UIImageView and a UIView that positions itself on top of image to show iPhone screens.
It worked in earlier releases because the image was a static size, but now I need the image to scale to fill in the screen for new devices like iPhone X. Think Aspect Fit is part of the answer.
I need the view in question to position properly across all iPhone devices and the simulators. 
I have some code that seems to work for devices but then that same code works differently in the Simulators.
I need the code to work the same in the simulators and devices as I do not have all devices to test with.

How can I, either through the story board or code, position a rectangle on top of an image that is being scaled by the system?
Need a universal solution that works across devices and in the simulator.

Am including rough code samples I have been experimenting with.

- The WeedplatesViewController.swift file contains the code for devices that seems to position properly for devices and then similar code I copied and was tweaking to test simulators that doesn’t position properly. Have a UIImage extension to create an image of the view and then some code to look for the black rectangle in the image. Using pixel comparison code found here on stack overflow.

On the Storyboard is the Weedpaper view controller that has a the Weedpaper title, "for Apple iPhone" text, the iPhone Image, the UIView  that I want to position properly on top of the iPhone image, "number of Weedpapers installed" text and a row of autosizing buttons along the bottom.

1. First got a tough lesson using the story board constraints to position the rectangle and it seems could get it to work in the story board but did not work on devices or the simulators.
2. Tried hard coding the position it seemed worked on devices but did not work on the simulator and vice versa and takes way to long to test and is obviously not the right way to do it.
3. Next modified the png file putting a black (255,255,255) rectangle in the iPhone image file, then in code, copied that view to a UIImage and tried looking for the black rectangle pixels that represent the frame. Once the pixels are found then should be able to position the view using those coordinates. But I am getting different screenshot bitmaps from devices vs simulators.
4. Also tried using AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: CGSize(width: w, height: h), insideRect: self.uiImageView.bounds) to no avail.

Need the UIView to position on top of the image which is being scaled by the system across devices and the simulator.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if (UIDevice.modelName.contains("Simulator"))
        {
            deviceName = ProcessInfo.init().environment["SIMULATOR_DEVICE_NAME"] ?? "NoN"
            bSimulator = true
        }
        else
        {
            deviceName = UIDevice.modelName
            bSimulator = false
        }

        print("deviceName:", deviceName)
        print("simulator:", bSimulator)

        var frame:CGRect!

        if bSimulator{
            frame = self.getImageRectForSimulators()
        }
        else
        {
            frame = self.getImageRectForDevices()
        }

        self.uiViewPhotos.frame = frame
        self.uiViewPhotos.isHidden = false
    }

    func getImageRectForDevices() -> CGRect
    {

        // Write the view to an image so we can get the positioning rectangle
        // Positioning Rectangle is a black rectangle in the image
        // it has the only true black pixels in the image

        let imgView:UIImageView = self.uiImageView
        let img:UIImage = self.uiImageView.asImage()


        // Write to the photo album for testing
        //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil)

        var pixelData = img.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
        var data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        let maxX = img.size.width
        let maxY = img.size.height
        let halfwayX = maxX / 2
        let halfwayY = maxY / 2

        let screenScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        let scaleFactorX = img.scale
        let scaleFactorY = img.scale * screenScale
        let screenFactor = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        let imgViewFactor = self.uiImageView.frame.width/self.uiImageView.frame.height

        var pnt:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: -1, y: -1)

        var pixelInfo: Int = -1
        var r:CGFloat!, g:CGFloat!
        var b:CGFloat!, a:CGFloat!
        var uiColor:UIColor!

        var v1:CGFloat!, v2:CGFloat!
        var v3:CGFloat!, v4:CGFloat!

        var newRect:CGRect!

        // Find this color in the image to locate the black pixel frame
        // use that to size the view accordingly
        // Seems to change among devices so round use black color

        let uiColor_phoneFramePixelColor = UIColor(red:0.0, green:0.0, blue:0.0, alpha:1.0)

        // Device code
        for i in stride(from: halfwayX*scaleFactorX, to: 0, by: -1)
        {
            pnt.x = i
            pnt.y = halfwayY*scaleFactorY

            pixelInfo = ((Int(img.size.width) * Int(pnt.y)) + Int(pnt.x)) * 4
            r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo])/CGFloat(255.0)
            g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1])/CGFloat(255.0)
            b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2])/CGFloat(255.0)
            a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3])/CGFloat(255.0)
            uiColor = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
            print("searching for i black pixel at i, y:", i, pnt.y, 255.0*r, 255.0*g, 255.0*b, a)
            if (uiColor == uiColor_phoneFramePixelColor)
            {
                v1 = i
                print("found i pixel at:", i)
                break
            }
        }
        print(" ")

        // find top y pixel
        // Device code
        for j in stride(from: halfwayY*scaleFactorY, to: 0, by: -1)
        {
            pnt.x = halfwayX*scaleFactorX
            pnt.y = j

            pixelInfo = ((Int(img.size.width) * Int(pnt.y)) + Int(pnt.x)) * 4
            r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo])/CGFloat(255.0)
            g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1])/CGFloat(255.0)
            b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2])/CGFloat(255.0)
            a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3])/CGFloat(255.0)
            uiColor = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
            print("searching for j black pixel at j, x:", j, pnt.x, 255.0*r, 255.0*g, 255.0*b, a)
            if (uiColor == uiColor_phoneFramePixelColor)
            {
                v2 = j
                print("found j pixel at:", j)
                break
            }
        }
        print(" ")

        // Find bottom x pixel
        // Device code
        for k in stride(from: halfwayX*scaleFactorX, to: maxX*scaleFactorX, by: 1)
        {
            pnt.x = k
            pnt.y = halfwayY

            pixelInfo = ((Int(img.size.width) * Int(pnt.y)) + Int(pnt.x)) * 4

            r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo])/CGFloat(255.0)
            g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1])/CGFloat(255.0)
            b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2])/CGFloat(255.0)
            a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3])/CGFloat(255.0)
            uiColor = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
            print("searching for k black pixel at k, y:", k, pnt.y, 255.0*r, 255.0*g, 255.0*b, a)
            if (uiColor == uiColor_phoneFramePixelColor)
            {
                v3 = k
                print("found bottom k pixel at:", k)
                break
            }
        }
        print(" ")

        // Find bottom y pixel
        // Device code
        for l in stride(from: halfwayY*scaleFactorY, to: maxY*scaleFactorY, by: 1)
        {
            pnt.x = halfwayX
            pnt.y = l

            pixelInfo = ((Int(img.size.width) * Int(pnt.y)) + Int(pnt.x)) * 4

            r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo])/CGFloat(255.0)
            g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1])/CGFloat(255.0)
            b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2])/CGFloat(255.0)
            a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3])/CGFloat(255.0)

            uiColor = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
            print("searching for l black pixel at l, x:", l, pnt.x, 255.0*r, 255.0*g, 255.0*b, a)

            if (uiColor == uiColor_phoneFramePixelColor)
            {
                v4 = l
                print("found bottom l pixel at:", l)
                break
            }
        }
        print(" ")

        // this is the Black Rectangle from the bitmap of the orginal image
        let w = (v3 - v1)
        let h = (v4 - v2)
        newRect = CGRect(x: v1/scaleFactorX, y: v2/scaleFactorY, width: w/scaleFactorX, height: h/scaleFactorY)

        print("calculated rectangle:", newRect)

        return newRect
    }

extension UIView {
    func asImage()-> UIImage
    {
        // Get an image of the view. Apple discourages using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
        // Starting with IOS 10 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext is sRBG only and 32 bit only.
        // Use UIGraphicsImageRenderer

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
            let renderFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
            renderFormat.opaque = false
            let renderedImage = renderer.image {
                rendererContext in
                layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
            }
            return renderedImage
        }
        else{
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
            self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return UIImage(cgImage: image!.cgImage!)
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `UIImage`, make sure it is pinned to the edges (0). Scaling the image depends on your image size and dimensions. See what works best. `Scale To Fill` could work.

For the `UIView`, you will likely need to play around with a variety of `NSLayoutConstraints` that activate and deactivate based upon the different screen sizes. `NSLayoutConstraint` has a class method called `activate()` that activates multiple constraints at once, which should allow Auto Layout to update its entire layout at the same time. For example:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
vw.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
vw.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
vw.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
vw.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.
```

Keep in mind, that these constraints can also be deactivated:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([
vw.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
vw.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
vw.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
vw.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor)
```

])

Comment: Thanks but my App is mostly using the autoresizing and when I try to set restraints I get runtime errors about conflicting restraints. I did notice if I could turn on the FlexibleLeftMargin and FlexibleRightMargin autoresizing masks on the View it pops into place for iPhone X's on the Storyboard but cant get that code to work either :( 
self.uiViewPhotos.autoResizingMask.update(with:.flexibleHeight, flexibleWidth) 
this changes the views autoresizing mask but the view does not seem to honor the new mask settings...Setting the SetNeedsDisplay doesn't help either...

Comment: Good luck and I hope that the question gets answered because I am curious of the different and quickest ways to do this. My answer would likely be very time consuming to implement in order to account for not only various screen sizes, but also the device orientations (i.e. portrait and landscape).

Comment: Got this working..Abandoned reading the screen looking for the frame in the Screenshot method as the pixel comparison code does not seem to work. The secret is to use Stack View. When I put everything in a stackview it kept the screen properly placed across all devices except iphone x's. For I phone x's I noticed that if I clicked the autoresized left and right margins in story board it popped into place. Was able to code autoresize for x's by setting the mask with a hard coded raw value. view.autosizingMask = UiView.AutoresizingMask(rawValue: 58) and it would only trigger if it was in a stack

Comment: So with everything in a Stack and the AutoResizingMask working was still a few pixels off so I modified the iPhone image by making the screen area transparent, and on story board put the screen view behind the iPhone image and sized view a couple pixels past the transparent area. That way iPhone image showed a nice border around the screen area on top while the image layed behind with a possibility of being few pixels off  but being clipped by the iPhone image view to show perfectly across iPhone Devices.

Comment: Although the problem is solved the question remains. Wonder why this pixel comparison code does not work? Seems like the pixels being read from the image are not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Apparently, UIStackViews are useful with auto resize and auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. Seems to work across the simulators and the devices I have : The pixel comparison code I was using was not working properly, here is the link that helped me figure it out: [Why do I get the wrong color of a pixel with following code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593706/why-do-i-get-the-wrong-color-of-a-pixel-with-following-code). Here is what worked for me. The iPhone image, not shown, is an iPhone image that has a black rectangle where you want the screen to be and is set to Aspect Fit.

```
private func getiPhoneScreenRect() -> (rect: CGRect, bOk: Bool){

// Write the view to an image so we can get the positioning rectangle
// Positioning Rectangle is a black rectangle in the image
// it has the only true black pixels in the image
// but the pixels may not be true black when we look at them so loosen
// equality criteria

let imgView:UIImageView = self.uiImageView
let img:UIImage = self.uiImageView.screenShotViaRenderImage()

let pixelData = img.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)
let bytesPerPixel = (img.cgImage?.bitsPerPixel)!
let bytesPerRow = img.cgImage!.bytesPerRow

let maxX = img.size.width
let maxY = img.size.height
let halfwayX = maxX / 2
let halfwayY = maxY / 2

let imgScale = img.scale

var pnt:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: -1, y: -1)

var pixelInfo: Int = -1
var r:CGFloat!, g:CGFloat!
var b:CGFloat!, a:CGFloat!

var v1:CGFloat = 0.0, v2:CGFloat = 0.0
var v3:CGFloat = 0.0, v4:CGFloat = 0.0

var newRect:CGRect!

// Find the black border in the image byfinding the black pixel frame
// use that to size the view accordingly
// Seems to change among devices so dont check for pure black

// From center towards left edge find black pixel

for i in stride(from: halfwayX*imgScale, to: 0, by: -1)
{
    pnt.x = i
    pnt.y = halfwayY*imgScale

    pixelInfo = Int(pnt.y) * bytesPerRow + Int(pnt.x) * 4
    r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo])/CGFloat(255.0)
    g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1])/CGFloat(255.0)
    b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2])/CGFloat(255.0)
    a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3])/CGFloat(255.0)

    // No true black in image so get close
    if (r*255.0 <= 3.0 && g*255.0 <= 3.0)
    {
        v1 = i
        break
    }
}

// From center towards top find top y pixel

for j in stride(from: halfwayY*imgScale, to: 0, by: -1)
{
    pnt.x = halfwayX*imgScale
    pnt.y = j

    pixelInfo = Int(pnt.y) * bytesPerRow + Int(pnt.x) * 4
    r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo])/CGFloat(255.0)
    g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1])/CGFloat(255.0)
    b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2])/CGFloat(255.0)
    a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3])/CGFloat(255.0)

    if (r*255.0 <= 3.0 && g*255.0 <= 3.0)
    {
        v2 = j
        break
    }
}

// From center towards bottom Find bottom x pixel

for k in stride(from:halfwayX*imgScale, to: maxX*imgScale-1, by: 1)
{
    pnt.x = k
    pnt.y = halfwayY*imgScale

    pixelInfo = Int(pnt.y) * bytesPerRow + Int(pnt.x) * 4
    r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo])/CGFloat(255.0)
    g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1])/CGFloat(255.0)
    b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2])/CGFloat(255.0)
    a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3])/CGFloat(255.0)

    if (r*255.0 <= 3.0 && g*255.0 <= 3.0)
    {
        v3 = k
        break
    }
}

// Find center towards right edge find bottom y pixel

for l in stride(from: halfwayY*imgScale, to: (maxY*imgScale)-1, by: 1)
{
    pnt.x = halfwayX*imgScale
    pnt.y = l

    pixelInfo = Int(pnt.y) * bytesPerRow + Int(pnt.x) * 4
    r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo])/CGFloat(255.0)
    g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1])/CGFloat(255.0)
    b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2])/CGFloat(255.0)
    a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3])/CGFloat(255.0)

    if (r*255.0 <= 3.0 && g*255.0 <= 3.0)
    {
        v4 = l
        break
    }
}

// If did not find rectangle return bOk false

if (v1 <= 0.0 || v2 <= 0.0 || v3 <= 0.0 || v4 <= 0.0)
    || v3 >= (maxX*imgScale)-1 || v4 >= (maxY*imgScale)-1
{
    return (newRect, false)
}

let w = (v3 - v1)
let h = (v4 - v2)

// this is the Black Rectangle from the bitmap of screenshot of the view
// inset the frame by 1 pixel

newRect = CGRect(x: (v1+2)/imgScale, y: (v2+2)/imgScale, width: (w-2)/imgScale, height: (h-2)/imgScale)

return (newRect, true)
```

}

Get the screen shot like this

```
extension UIView {
func screenShotViaRenderImage()-> UIImage
{
    // Get an image of the view. Apple discourages using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    // Starting with IOS 10 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext is sRBG only and 32 bit only.
    // Use UIGraphicsImageRenderer

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let rendererFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
        rendererFormat.opaque = false
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds, format: rendererFormat)
        let screenShot = renderer.image {
            rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
        return screenShot
    }
    else{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return UIImage(cgImage: screenShot!.cgImage!)
    }
}
```

}

then call it like this

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    // Different images depending on where we call it from viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear
    // This will make the screen size into the black rectangle in the phone image
    // the image looses detail so the black frame may not be totally black
    //

    let iPhoneScreenFrame = self.getiPhoneScreenRect()
    if (iPhoneScreenFrame.bOk)
    {
        self.someScreen.frame = iPhoneScreenFrame.rect
    }
}
```