# Converting UIImage to CGImage to get Pixel Color

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage

Based on code from this question ([How do I get the color of a pixel in a UIImage with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146557/how-do-i-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-a-uiimage-with-swift)), I'm trying to run a function when a button gets tapped. Here is my code thus far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var graphImage: UIImageView!

var image : UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {
    var pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.image!.CGImage))
    var data : UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

    var pixelInfo : Int = ((Int(image!.size.width) * Int(pos.y) + Int(pos.x)*4))

    let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo])
    let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]+1)
    let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]+2)
    let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]+3)

    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
}

@IBAction func playTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var c : CGFloat = 100.0
    var d : CGFloat = 100.0
    getPixelColor(CGPoint(x:c,y:d))
}
```

However, whenever I tap the play button in the iOS Simulator, the app crashes and I get the warning "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the first line of the function getPixelColor. What am I doing wrong here/what do I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight forward. Based on the code here, you are indeed unwrapping a `nil` object. Your instance variable, `image`, is never initialized to anything... So you're trying to force unwrap it with `!` but it is actually `nil`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that when I debug, the image object is in fact not nil, but the variable pixelData is. I'm quite new to coding, so I have no idea if this means that my image object still isn't the problem. Anyway, how would I initialize this variable? I tried just saying "var image = graphImage," but then I get an error on the third line of the function getPixelColor saying UIImageView has no member size.

Comment: Without getting into the details of your project - the point is that your variable `image` is `nil`. It's up to you, or another question to figure out why. Good luck!