# Swift 3: get color of pixel in UIImage (better: UIImageView)

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage

I tried different solutions (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146557/how-do-i-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-a-uiimage-with-swift)), but the color I get back looks a bit different than in the real image. I guess it's because the image is only `RGB`, not `RGBA`. May that be an issue?

Related issue: if the UIImage has `contentMode = .scaleAspectFill`, do I have to do a recalculation of the image or can I just use `imageView.image`?

EDIT:

I tried with this extension:

```
extension CALayer {
    func getPixelColor(point: CGPoint) -> CGColor {
        var pixel: [CUnsignedChar] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)

        let context = CGContext(data: &pixel, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

        context!.translateBy(x: -point.x, y: -point.y)

        self.render(in: context!)

        let red: CGFloat   = CGFloat(pixel[0]) / 255.0
        let green: CGFloat = CGFloat(pixel[1]) / 255.0
        let blue: CGFloat  = CGFloat(pixel[2]) / 255.0
        let alpha: CGFloat = CGFloat(pixel[3]) / 255.0


        let color = UIColor(red:red, green: green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)

        return color.cgColor
    }
}
```

but for some images it seems as if the coordinate system is turned around, for others I get really wrong values... what am I missing here?

EDIT 2:

I try with these images:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/119600/gradient.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/119600/gradient@2x.png

but I do get wrong values. They are embedded in a `UIImageView` but I convert the coordinates:

```
private func convertScreenPointToImage(point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    let widthMultiplier = gradientImage.size.width / UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let heightMultiplier = gradientImage.size.height / UIScreen.main.bounds.height

    return CGPoint(x: point.x * widthMultiplier, y: point.y * heightMultiplier)
}
```

This one

[image]

gives me `=== Optional((51, 76, 184, 255))` when running on the iPhone 7 simulator, which is not correct...

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this is a playground.  I index into the image data with a pointer and grab the rgba values:

```swift
func pixel(in image: UIImage, at point: CGPoint) -> (UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)? {
    let width = Int(image.size.width)
    let height = Int(image.size.height)
    let x = Int(point.x)
    let y = Int(point.y)
    guard x < width && y < height else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let cfData:CFData = image.cgImage?.dataProvider?.data, let pointer = CFDataGetBytePtr(cfData) else {
        return nil
    }
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let offset = (x + y * width) * bytesPerPixel
    return (pointer[offset], pointer[offset + 1], pointer[offset + 2], pointer[offset + 3])
}

let image = UIImage(named: "t.png")!
if let (r,g,b,a) = pixel(in: image, at: CGPoint(x: 1, y:2)) {
    print ("Red: \(r), Green: \(g), Blue: \(b), Alpha: \(a)")
}
```

Note that if you use this on a UIImage that is a property of a UIImageView the pixel coordinates are those of the actual image in its original resolution, not the screen coordinates of the scaled UIImageView.  Also it tried with RGB Jpg and RGBA PNG and the both get imported as 32 bit RGBA images so it works for both.

Comment: I can't get it to work correctly, I still get wrong values :( Please see my edit

Comment: The code is correct; I just checked it with your first image.  I opened photoshop, switched to the eyedropper tool and opened the info palette.  I hover over the pixel at x = 120, y = 500 and photoshop says r:175 g: 146 b 232.  I run the code in the playground and I get Red 175, Green: 146, Blue :232, Alpha: 255.  What are your inputs and what are your expected outputs?

Comment: I get different values (see my edit) - how do you load the image?

Comment: load it as in the playground let image = UIImage (named: "gradient.png")! and I bet that is the problem.  You are loading from the asset catalog so you are getting the @2x image.  Whereas I am directly loading the 1X image.