# SwiftUI - Get pixel color from Image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI image displayed like this:

```
Image("Map")
     .resizable()
     .gesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
          .onChanged { value in
              self.position = value.location
              print(position)
              let color = getColor(at: position)
              print(color)
           }
           .onEnded { _ in
              self.position = .zero
           }
        )
```

and a getColor function:

```
func getColor(at point: CGPoint) -> UIColor{

        let pixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: 4)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
        let context = CGContext(data: pixel, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

        context.translateBy(x: -point.x, y: -point.y)
        let color = UIColor(red:   CGFloat(pixel[0]) / 255.0,
                            green: CGFloat(pixel[1]) / 255.0,
                            blue:  CGFloat(pixel[2]) / 255.0,
                            alpha: CGFloat(pixel[3]) / 255.0)

        pixel.deallocate()
        return color
    }
```

When I launch the app and touch the Image, the position is well displayed on the console but the color returns 0 0 0 0, example:

```
(262.3333282470703, 691.6666564941406)
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 0
```

After a long search, I didn't find a way to get a pixel color from an Image in SwiftUI, if someone has a solution or can help me, it would be really nice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146557/how-do-i-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-a-uiimage-with-swift

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but this solution is for UIKit, not SwiftUI right ?

Comment: SwiftUI does not expose a CoreGraphics API context. Since you are trying to get the values via CGContext (UIKit way), that is probably root of the issue you are having. Another approach to your problem could be using CoreImage API's, an example [here](https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-read-the-average-color-of-an-image-c736adb43000)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4930934/burak-akkaş - it now does, through `ImageRenderer`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a more complicated solution than necessary, but it works.

Basically, it creates a memory-based copy of the `Image` using an `ImageRenderer`, whilst the actual dimensions of the visible `Image` are captured by a `GeometryReader`. The difference in sizes are used to scale the drag-position.

The memory-based view can then be queried for its `cgImage` property, and the `CGImage` pixel picked out at the scaled drag coordinate.

Here's the code - it shows an image (I crop it to a circle as it's a colour wheel, but that's not necessary), overlays a cursor, shows the cursor coordinates and the `Color` under the cursor:

```
//
//  PixelPickerView.swift
//  PixelPicker
//
//  Created by Grimxn on 18/11/2023.
//

import SwiftUI

struct PixelPickerView: View {
    @State private var cursor = CGPoint.zero.  // Drag position
    @State private var colourSelected: Color?  // Pixel Color
    @State private var x = 0                   // Scaled drag x
    @State private var y = 0                   // Scaled drag y
    @State private var myImage = Image("ColourWheel")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { g in
                let diameter: CGFloat = min(g.size.width, g.size.height)
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    myImage
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .overlay {
                            cursor(diameter: diameter)
                        }
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                .onChanged {
                                    cursor = $0.location
                                }
                                .onEnded {_ in
                                    colourAtOffset(diameter: diameter)
                                }
                        )
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            Text("\(x), \(y)")
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundStyle(colourSelected ?? .clear)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    private func colourAtOffset(diameter: CGFloat) {
        Task {
            if let cgi = await ImageRenderer(content: myImage).cgImage {
                if let dp = cgi.dataProvider,
                   let pixelData = dp.data {
                    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

                    x = Int(CGFloat(cgi.width) * cursor.x / diameter)
                    y = Int(CGFloat(cgi.height) * cursor.y / diameter)
                    let pixelInfo: Int = (cgi.bytesPerRow * y) + x * 4
                    if cgi.bitmapInfo.contains(.byteOrderDefault) {
                        let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo + 0]) / CGFloat(255)
                        let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo + 1]) / CGFloat(255)
                        let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo + 2]) / CGFloat(255)
                        let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo + 3]) / CGFloat(255)
                        colourSelected = Color(red: r, green: g, blue: b, opacity: a)
                    } else {
                        colourSelected = .brown // Brown for debug, should be `nil`
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func cursor(diameter: CGFloat) -> some View {
        let r = diameter / 2
        let wee = CGFloat(5)
        let p = Path { p in
            p.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: r))
            p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r - wee, y: r))
            p.move(to: CGPoint(x: r + wee, y: r))
            p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 2 * r, y: r))
            
            p.move(to: CGPoint(x: r, y: 0))
            p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r, y: r - wee))
            p.move(to: CGPoint(x: r, y: r + wee))
            p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r, y: 2 * r))
        }
        
        return p.stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 3)
            .offset(cursorOffset(diameter: diameter))
    }
    
    private func cursorOffset(diameter: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(width: cursor.x - diameter / 2,
               height: cursor.y - diameter / 2)
    }
}

#Preview {
    PixelPickerView()
}
```

[image]