# How to get pixel color from image while dragging in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, linear-gradients, color-picker

I wanted to create custom color picker in swift UI and i tried with image and trying to find out the pixel on specific location.

[Image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdZDM.jpg)

**My solution is below:**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ImageColorPicker: View {
    
    @State private var draggedColor: Color = .black
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("Picker")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
                        .onChanged { value in
                            if let pixelColor = getPixelColor(at: value.location) {
                                draggedColor = Color(pixelColor)
                            }
                        }
                )
            
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(draggedColor)
                .frame(width: 100,height: 100)
        }
    }
    
    private func getPixelColor(at point: CGPoint) -> UIColor? {
        guard let image = UIImage(named: "Picker"),
              let cgImage = image.cgImage,
              let pixelData = cgImage.dataProvider?.data else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)
        let bytesPerPixel = cgImage.bitsPerPixel / 8
        let bytesPerRow = cgImage.bytesPerRow
        let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(point.y) * bytesPerRow) + (Int(point.x) * bytesPerPixel))
        
        let red = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo + 1]) / 255.0
        let blue = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo + 2]) / 255.0
        let alpha = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo + 3]) / 255.0
        
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
    
    
}
```

Could any one help me what's wrong i am doing here.

Comment: Please see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67018273/swiftui-get-pixel-color-from-image/77507445#77507445