# Check for Collision Between Two UIImageViews - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, collision

I have two png files that have some transparent areas in them. I want to check if the non transparent parts are colliding.

CGRectIntersectsRect doesn't work for me.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much information about the context, but if performance isn't an issue you could just compare the images pixel by pixel to see where transparent and non-transparent pixels are overlapping.

See this answer here to see how to get access to the actual pixel information based on a UIImage. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7101544/974782

Answer (score 0):

break it into 2 pieces:

1. get a outlining CGPath from the images
2. see, if the paths intersects each other.

For both you should find some codes.