# How to detect the color of an UIImage in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uicolor, cgimage, uiscreen

I have a view like this :

[image]

The **left back button & the right button** is basically two white image (set in `UIButton`) with a particular opacity. Now it's look more or less visible on this background cover photo.

But if I change the background cover photo with something else, where the opacity & color of that cover image is closer to the two button's image, then it's difficult to see those two button.

Like this:

[image]

So I just wondering, Is there any way, so that I can detect the color of my cover image and I can change those two buttons image or color according to it?

Any kind of reference or guidance would be very much appreciable.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284185/get-pixel-color-of-uiimage

Comment: yoe set black color with alpha 60% because image is transparent not detect color.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks for the link. :)

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya Yes you are right. But what's the point?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use [this function](http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Retrieve_the_color_of_a_pixel_at_a_specific_poin-Gnd) to determinate how light/dark is the background. Calculate an average of several pixel under your button.

Have fun! :D