# Calculate opaque color from alpha + background?

Tags: ios

I want to "lighten" a certain color by applying an alpha of 0.3 to it. This is shown on a white background.

I would like to determine the opaque color which corresponds to this semi transparent color shown on a white background. The reason is that I use this as view controllers's background color, and when this background is semitransparent the transitions look bad.

I have not tried anything because have no idea about a reasonable way to approach this except maybe taking a snapshot and get the color of it but this seems a bit of an overkill. Can't find any infos, search results are cluttered with "how to make a background semitransparent" etc

**Edit**: Putting together imataptool's answer parts (and porting to Swift), this is what I came up with:

```
extension UIColor {

    static func opaqueColorByDisplayingTransparentColorOnBackground(transparentColor: UIColor, backgroundColor: UIColor) -> UIColor {

        let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1))
        bgView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        let overlayView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1))
        overlayView.backgroundColor = transparentColor
        bgView.addSubview(overlayView)

        let image = UIView.imageWithView(bgView)

        let provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage)
        let pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider)
        let data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat(data[0]) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat(data[1]) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(data[2]) / 255.0,
            alpha: 1
        )
    }
}

extension UIView {

    // src http://stackoverflow.com/a/32042439/930450
    class func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
        view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }
}
```

Comment: you can addSubView a label to your UIView then make the UILabel trancparent instead of UIView

Comment: I don't really want to have to add more views to the hierarchy... it's an acceptable workaround though.

Comment: Ok for background don't use white color use another color code near white -> like smoky

Comment: Not seeing how having only 1 background view this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit 1: This isn't to say this is the best way to achieve your specific goal, but it does solve the problem of getting the RGB of a mix of two colors with a particular opacity. You haven't provided enough information about what exactly you are doing for me to give a more specific answer. However, if this solution does what you need with acceptable performance, excellent, run with it.*

*Edit 2: Refer to [this Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html) for new (ish) methods for rendering UIView as bitmaps as of iOS 7 (so if you are supporting iOS 6 you can ignore this, but that's unlikely). The gist of the article is that you can now use the UIView method* `-drawViewHierarchyInRect:(CGRect)afterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)`

I can't say whether or not there exists a mathematical way to calculate the exact answer, but one way of going about it would be:

1. Add the two views to a parent view (with the opaque view below the transparent view)
2. Convert the parent view (and all of its subviews) to a UIImage
3. Sample the UIImage for the color it is composed of

Doing 1 is trivial. You can do 2 with

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage* img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return img;
```

Now `img` contains an image with the color you want. Now you just need to figure out what color it is composed of. I believe you can do that with the code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284185/get-pixel-color-of-uiimage). I'll copy it here for convenience.

```
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width  * y) + x ) * 4; // The image is png

UInt8 red = data[pixelInfo];         // If you need this info, enable it
UInt8 green = data[(pixelInfo + 1)]; // If you need this info, enable it
UInt8 blue = data[pixelInfo + 2];    // If you need this info, enable itgame
CFRelease(pixelData);
```

`red`, `green`, and `blue` now contain the RGB values of the color at whatever point you pick in your view. You might as well just go to the middle of it. **Also, to improve the performance of this process, you might choose to only image a small subsection of the view in question (maybe just one pixel).**

Comment: This is what I was thinking, create a snapshot and get color from pixels... I'd put it in an extension, a function color+alpha+bg color-> color, of course use an image which is 1x1, more is not necessary. Wondered if there's no simpler way. But I'll just implement this. Thanks for the details.

Comment: Sure. Just one note (I'll edit) there are new methods for rendering views as bitmaps as of iOS 7. There's literature on it.

Comment: Ah, yes, you probably mean snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates & co

Comment: Well, actually *not* snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates. That method isn't recommended for this purpose (at least, Apple uses drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: in the 2013 WWDC video).

Comment: Ok, I was talking generally about the extension for iOS 7 which has snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates, resizableSnapshotViewFromRect and drawViewHierarchyInRect. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Glad you got a working solution. Swift will never feel natural to me!

Answer (score 1):

If somebody will be looking for more straightforward solution, this [post about combining colors applying specific alpha](https://www.weheartswift.com/combining-colors/) might be helpful.

TLDR

```
extension UIColor {

    func combining(with color: UIColor, fraction f: CGFloat) -> UIColor {

        let source = components()
        let target = color.components()

        return UIColor(
            red:   interpolate(from: source.r, to: target.r, fraction: f),
            green: interpolate(from: source.g, to: target.g, fraction: f),
            blue:  interpolate(from: source.b, to: target.b, fraction: f),
            alpha: 1
        )
    }

    private typealias Components = (
        r: CGFloat,
        g: CGFloat,
        b: CGFloat,
        a: CGFloat
    )

    private func components() -> Components {

        var result: Components = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        getRed(&result.r, green: &result.g, blue: &result.b, alpha: &result.a)

        return result
    }
}

func interpolate(from a: CGFloat, to b: CGFloat, fraction: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    (1 - fraction) * a + fraction * b
}
```