# How can I get RGB value from CGImage in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

In my iOS application I can show a image in UIImageView, then I want to get the pixel's RGB value from the UIImageView.

How do I do that?

This is Xamarin.iOS project in C#. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get RGB value of a pixel in UIImage, you have to work with CGImage actually.

So you have UIImageView which uses UIImage. To get CGImage you have to use `UIImage.CGImage` property and then use any of the available solutions.
For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28528496/883738)

Alternative options: [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

Answer (score -1):

```
Thanks for Alex Sorokoletov, Now ,I have a solution for my project , It is like this:

        nint pixLen = imageWidth * imageHeigh;
        nint count = pixLen  * 4 ;
        byte[] newImageArr = new byte[count];
 using (var context = new CGBitmapContext(newImageArr, imageWidth, imageHeigh,
            bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast))
        {

            RectangleF imageRec = new RectangleF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeigh);

            context.DrawImage(imageRec, myCgImage);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i = i+4)
            {

                float clorRed = (newImageArr[i]) ;
                float clorGreen = (newImageArr[i + 1]) ;
                float clorBlue = (newImageArr[i + 2]) ;
            }
       }
```

Comment: Where does colorSpace live?