# How to find the CGColor at a CGPoint in a CGImage

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, cgimage

I am trying to find the `CGColor` at a `CGPoint` in a `CGImage`. There are multiple Stack Overflow posts that have something similar (like `UIImage` instead of `CGImage` or Objective C instead of Swift), but nothing specific enough to help me.

Does anyone know how to get the color at a point? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Pixel color of UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284185/get-pixel-color-of-uiimage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im assuming based on your `macOS` tag that you want to do this on macOS and thus can use `NSImage` and `NSBitmapImageRep`:

```
let cgImage = //your CGImage
let bitmap = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: cgImage)
if let colorAtPoint = bitmap.colorAt(x: 0, y: 0) {
  let cgColor = colorAtPoint.cgColor
  print(cgColor)
}
```

Comment: The x and y values in colorAt(x:y:) are Ints-- how do I convert from CGFloat to Int without losing precision?

Comment: This is getting into a tricky area of display resolution, pixels vs points, etc. The `colorAt` returns a value at a specified `pixel` -- that's why `x,y` are `Int`. If you have a `CGFloat` from, say, a position on the screen, you'll need to make sure you're converting between pixels and points.

Comment: Thanks. Is the conversion pixel = point * resolution?

Comment: This depends on how you have it displayed. Let's say you have a 300 pixel image and it's being displayed in 150 points on the screen -- then your screen density is 2x and each 1 pt on the screen would be 2 px.